# Is there a way to change network interface without rebooting the operating system AND disconnecting the network?

Tags: debian, centos, configuration, network-interface

I understand that in order to change the espn0 to eth0 without rebooting, I could do the following with script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip link set espn0 down
ip link set espn0 name eth0
ip link set eth0 up
```

It works perfectly on normal desktop. But for a server with `ssh` access only when I run the above script,

From the first statement:
`ip link set espn0 down`

That already bring down the server internet connection and I got disconnected from the SSH login.

So, how do I change espn0 interface to eth0 without rebooting and without disconnecting the internet connection especially i'm still connecting the SSH? Is it possible ?

Comment: I think you edited my question wrongly. saying that the script will not run. That is not correct.

Comment: Rolled back, Now make it clear. My edit shows that it is being miss-interpreted.

Comment: Which is the statement  that cause confusion?

Comment: See my edit. it will show how I interpreted the text.

Comment: What do you mean by miss-interpreted? Are saying that 'You are being miss-interpreted' or 'I am being miss-interpreted' Sorry I dont get it because you said 'it is being miss interpreted'. It's good that you help correcting grammar but changing some of the question based on your opinion is not a good ethic (IMO)

Comment: @A.B That's the reason, but there must be some magic-way to solve this. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as would be seen on a system with address 192.0.2.2/24 with gateway 192.0.2.1 if it didn't get unreachable:

```
# ip route
default via 192.0.2.1 dev espn0 
192.0.2.0/24 dev espn0 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.2.2 

# ip link set espn0 down
# ip link set espn0 name eth0
# ip link set eth0 up

# ip route
192.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.2.2
```

While the LAN route is automatically added back by the kernel from the address because it's a `proto kernel` route, there's no such mechanism for the default route. Without default route the connectivity is lost.

I propose to use a rarely used feature of [`ip route`](https://manpages.debian.org/ip-route.8): `ip route save`/`ip route restore`:

> `ip route save`
> save routing table information to stdout
>
> This command behaves like ip route show except that the output is raw
> data suitable for passing to ip route restore.

and:

> `ip route restore`
> restore routing table information from stdin
>
> This command expects to read a data stream as returned from ip route
> save. It will attempt to restore the routing table information exactly
> as it was at the time of the save, so any translation of information
> in the stream (such as device indexes) must be done first. Any
> existing routes are left unchanged. Any routes specified in the data
> stream that already exist in the table will be ignored.

This will work here because internally routes are handled (and here saved) with interface indexes, not interface names. Renaming an interface doesn't change its index.

Script to use:

```
ip route save default > /tmp/mysaveddefaultroute
ip link set espn0 down
ip link set espn0 name eth0
ip link set eth0 up
ip route restore < /tmp/mysaveddefaultroute
```

and in the end:

```
# ip route
default via 192.0.2.1 dev eth0 
192.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.2.2
```

Caveats:

- firewall specific rules to check
- if the script ever outputs anything, it might get stuck since unable to output. Running the script in background would then be necessary
- the system might have other routes to deal with. Adapt
- it could be using DHCP. If DHCP is used, this won't work properly without reconfiguring DHCP, eg it will suddenly become unreachable once some DHCP event happens

Comment: If this wasn't clear: that's the loss of default route after the operations that causes the problems. This default route must be put back

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and will come back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run the script via nohup and put it in the background so that when your connection is dropped, the script will continue to run.

e.g.  `nohup ./myscript &`

Comment: No, I don't think the script will terminate after the first statement when the internet is disconnected. So running with nohup has no advantage. The script will run and finish but the problem here I dont want to be disconnected because I will have other codes after that 3 lines to run. Also, the method of changing the interface above is not persistent on boot so, it wont work even the script finished executed.

Comment: What about creating a virtual interface with it's own IP (ie. espn0:1) and ssh'ing into that.  Then downing/renaming the other interface might not matter.

Comment: but that will involve switching between virtual interface and cause disconnected? I'm not sure how to go with this.

Comment: So are you asking with or without the reboot? Title said without re-boot, now you say including re-boot.

Comment: Please revert back what you have changed. The title said what I said, you added something that was not right like the script wasn't run. and then I can explain. If grammar is mistake just edit that one dont edit others.

Comment: I think if you created a virtual interface and then ssh'ed into it, you should be able to down the other interface & rename it without being dropped.  Once that's done, you could then ssh into the original IP and remove the virtual interface.  There is no way to stay connected to an interface when you down it so you'll need a temporary connection of some sort.

Comment: @mikem I understand the concept you have given, but I don't think it's a good idea in my case because I need to run this one time script to change other settings, so the script need to continue running. I cannot run 2 SSH and providing one script to this 2 different interfaces. because my script actually has conditional checking to see what is the current interface name is. if it is not eth0, then rename .. etc.

Comment: I think I will accept this answer (in comment) if no other answer is given because I think it is not possible and this is the closest working method. I just need to figure out how to switch the interface via script. I will accept this once I able to use this method correctly in bash. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks -- Good luck!

Comment: I mean answer from the comment. Perhaps you should include that in the post.

Comment: Also, for @ctrl-alt-delor, it's funny that you changed my question and exclude the 'reboot' title then you asked me to explain whether I want to include reboot or not because the title said without 'reboot'. I think someone need to evaluate your privilege on edit. But now I'm glad you reverted that back to my original title because the title you suggested is duplicated. Not sure what is your intention here and when I ask which is the confusion statement you said my question is being miss-interpreted. The edit history tells everything about this.

Comment: What I have done is discover a miss-understanding, this is valuable information for you.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor i'm sorry if that was just misunderstanding. thanks for helping correcting that grammar.